# Map between types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

When I define a Sequelize schema in TypeScript, I have to generate a runtime type for Sequelize and a static type for TypeScript:

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize';
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

// Sequelize Schema
const userSchema = {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  birthday: Sequelize.DATE
};

// TypeScript type
interface UserType {
  username: string;
  birthday: Date;
}

const User = sequelize.define<Sequelize.Instance<UserType>, UserType>('user', userSchema);
```

There's no way around defining the runtime sequelize schema. But ideally the TypeScript type could be derived from it to reduce duplication.

Looking at the [DefinitelyTyped definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9ddeb8513f42c1859c175c23f98901e7ac95dfb9/sequelize/index.d.ts#L1873-L1905) for sequelize 4, `Sequelize.STRING` and `Sequelize.DATE` each have different types: `DataTypeString` and `DataTypeNumber`, respectively. So perhaps it's possible to map the types?

You can map the individual types using function overloading:

```
declare function mapTypes(x: typeof Sequelize.NUMBER): number;
declare function mapTypes(x: typeof Sequelize.DATE): Date;

let foo = mapTypes(Sequelize.NUMBER);  // foo has type number!
```

But it's not clear how to map `typeof userSchema` onto the full `UserType` interface. This feels like the mapped types feature from TypeScript 2.1, but this doesn't quite work:

```
type UserSchemaT = typeof userSchema;
type UserType = {[K in keyof UserSchemaT]: typeof mapTypes(K)};
                                                          ~~~
                                                       // [ts] Cannot find name 'K'.
```

Is it possible to construct a new type by mapping from one type to another with TypeScript? Can I generate the interface type from the type of the schema object?

Answer (score 2):

The sequelize API has [changed considerably](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/upgrade-to-v5.html) in the three years since this question was asked. But just to close the loop for myself, this is exactly the sort of mapping that [conditional types](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/conditional-types-in-typescript) were designed to let you do.

Here's how you'd update the example in the question to generate the `UserType` type from the schema value.

```
import Sequelize, {DataTypes} from 'sequelize';
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

// This is a union of the TypeScript types for all possible sequelize data types.
type SequelizeDataTypes = DataTypes[keyof DataTypes];

// Map from Sequelize types to TypeScript types for a single value.
type SequelizeToTs<T extends SequelizeDataTypes> =
  T extends typeof Sequelize.NUMBER ? number :
  T extends typeof Sequelize.STRING ? string :
  T extends typeof Sequelize.DATE ? Date :
  // ...
  never;

// Map between types for a full instance.
type TypeForSchema<T extends Record<string, SequelizeDataTypes>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: SequelizeToTs<T[K]>;
};

// Sequelize Schema
const userSchema = {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  birthday: Sequelize.DATE
};

type UserType = TypeForSchema<typeof userSchema>;
// type UserType = {
//   username: string;
//   birthday: Date;
// }

const User = sequelize.define<Sequelize.Instance<UserType>, UserType>('user', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, `mapTypes(K)` is not valid TypeScript because `mapTypes` expects value for its argument, not a type. Second, `typeof` can't be applied to arbitrary expression like function call, it works only for variables.

In general, Typescript has mapped types, but current implementation has certain limits. I don't know of any way to use arbitrary type as a key to map it to another type. It looks like it's only possible to use [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) as keys.

As an example of what's possible with current TypeScript (2.2.1), you can have a look at my project: [warning: work in progress, not published on npm yet](https://github.com/fictitious/antireflection/blob/master/packages/antireflection/README.md):

```
import * as ar from 'antireflection';

const pointType = ar.object({ // this is ordinary object initializer
    x: ar.number,  // ar.number (and ar.string) are just objects defined in antireflection.ts
    y: ar.number
});

type Point = ar.Type<typeof pointType>;

// it's the same as type Point = {x: number, y: number};
// but now you have its description at runtime:
// pointType.p() returns an object with Point type properties

// so, for example, you can check the type at run time:

const errors = ar.check(pointType, {x: 'a'});
console.dir(errors);
// x: expected number, got string
// y: expected number, got undefined
```

I don't think anything like this is currently possible with sequelize. A cursory look at it confirms that `Sequelize.STRING` and `Sequelize.DATE` are indeed distinct types, but they don't seem to have anything suitable as key   for mapped type.

Comment: The TypeScript folks confirmed that this isn't possible yet: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14372

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [dts-gen](https://github.com/Microsoft/dts-gen)

If you're doing GraphQL, I like: [gql-gen](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator)

Cheers